# Is there any way in Python to reduce/expand my code similar to the R function of "{ }"?

Tags: python, reduce, expand

I have written quite a complex program in Python 3.7. However I am looking for a way to reduce (and later on expand again) my already functional functions. So that I don't have to scroll over 200 lines of code whenever I want to get back to the top.

As I said, I am writing my code in Python 3.7 and this seems like a pretty easy/beginner technique. However, I tried googling a lots of stuff, unfortunately English is not my native language and I have no idea of what to google. And googling for "reduce code in Python" ain't gonna work me. Thus I am hoping you Geeks could help me! :)

E.g.

Instead of

```
1 # This is some random code

2 print("Hello")

3 print("beautiful")

4 print("World")

5 # This is some random code
```

I want to have

```
1 # This is some random code

2-4 # Here all the other lines should be reduced to one line

5 # This is some random code
```

Comment: Better use an IDE preferably PyCharm to do such folding and unfolding tasks. That's pretty much a click away.

Comment: `reducing` to one line also mean different things in python. for example, for loops can be reduced into what we call `list` or `dictionary` comprehesion. I assume you are talking about reducing code size by refactoring

Comment: Use IDE PyCharm or Anaconda, that may help you

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I am already using Anaconda, but haven't figured a way out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize code folding in an IDE. Suggested IDES for Anaconda can be found [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/). I'd recommend Visual Studio Code.
[image: IDE for anaconda]